# Google Analytics: Using adv. filter to transform event into pageview

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, web-analytics

I've got 3 events that I need to transform into pageviews:

They have same category and action, but different labels. Let's assume it looks like this

Category: Interface
Action: Log-In
Label 1: Product-Page
Label 2: Log-In-Page
Label 3: Listing-Page

I need to transform them into pageviews, so I applied an advanced filter, screenshotted below

To my surprise, the events disappeared, but no pageview came up. Any tips?
:[image]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not using field B, as you have in the output $A1/$A2, but you don't have an A2. You should have $A1/$B1 instead.